# How to get nested collection from Firebase Firestore on Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an application where I have saved my data in firebase Firestore in nested collection now when I am trying to get/retrieve the data from Firestore but not able to get it. please guide me where am I wrong??

**CODE TO WRITE/ADD THE DATA IN FIRESTORE**

```
  DocumentReference uidRef =  firebaseFirestore.collection("listing_details").document(uid);

    uidRef.collection("room_details").add(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "data added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


       }
   })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "data adding failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

**CODE FOR DATA RETRIEVING**

```
  db.collection("listing_details").document().collection("room_details").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
            for (DocumentSnapshot d : list)
            {
                RoomsDetails obj = d.toObject(RoomsDetails.class);
                roomsDetails.add(obj);
            }
            roomsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

**DATA RETRIEVING CODE (UPDATED)**

```
  roomDetailsRef.document(doc_id).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

        //GUIDE ME HERE HOW CAN I ITERATE THROUGH IT SIR PLEASE
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: "not able to get it" is really hard to help with. If you set a breakpoint of each line of the code you shared, run in a debugger and check the value of each variable on each line, what is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sir please check my retrieving code i think the problem is in this code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you're calling `.document()` to create the following reference, without passing anything as an argument:

```
db.collection("listing_details").document().collection("room_details")
//
```

It means that you're generating a brand new unique document ID. If you want to create a reference that points to a particular document, then you have to pass the particular document ID that already exists in the database to the `document()` method, and **not** generate a new one.

So your code should look like this:

```
//Code to add data to Firestore.
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference uidRef =  db.collection("listing_details").document(uid);
CollectionReference roomDetailsRef = uidRef.collection("room_details");
String docId = roomDetailsRef.document().getId();
roomDetailsRef.document(docId).set(user).addOnSuccessListener(/*.../*);
//
```

See, I have used [DocumentReference#getId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#getId()) to get the ID of the document, and [DocumentReference#set(Object data)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#set(java.lang.Object)) to actually add the document to Firestore.

```
//Code to read data from Firestore.
roomDetailsRef.document(docId).get().addOnSuccessListener(/*.../*);
//
```

See, I have passed the document ID that was generated earlier, to the [CollectionReference#document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#document()) method.

**Edit:**

If you want to get all documents that exist under the `room_details` collection, then please use the following lines of code:

```
roomDetailsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document != null) {
                    RoomsDetails obj = document.toObject(RoomsDetails.class);
                    roomsDetails.add(obj);
                }
            }
            roomsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sir Data added completely fine thanks but the problem is in the data retreiving.  i dont know how to iterate through it. I have added the code above please check.

Comment: If you want to read a single document, you should use the solution in my answer, if you want to retrive multiple documents from a collection,  you can the code from "CODE FOR DATA RETRIEVING".

Comment: Yes sir I want to retrieve multiple documents and I am using that code but i am not able to iterate please guide me on that

Comment: Ok, then please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Yes sir it is showing sir but when I am trying to log in with another number then it is not showing

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "log in with another number". Besides that, questions that derive from the initial question should be added separately. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial problem?

Comment: no sir thank you ok I am going to post another question, thank you for your great help always. You are a mentor for me on StackOverFlow thanks A Lot Sir